# WebGL bufferSubData is not working when trying to set a point size during a mousemove event

Tags: events, webgl, mousemove

I want to draw different point sizes during mousemove events using webGL.  For example, I press the mouse and draw points with size of 1 pixel.  Then select a different size and when I press the mouse and move, I can draw points with the new size.

I discovered something strange and will really appreciate any feedback.

1. I created an array of point sizes:

   ```
   var pointSizes = new Uint8Array(2000);
   ```
2. I added an attribute to the shader to get the point sizes:

   ```
   attribute float pointSize;
   ```

   the main function has:
     gl_PointSize = pointSize;
3. If I populate the array with a size, everything works fine as long as I do not bind in the mousemove event:

   ```
   for(var i = 0; i<=1999; i++)
       {pointSizes[i] = 5.0;}  //draw points of size 5


   aPointSizeBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, aPointSizeBuffer);
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointSizes, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
   aPointSize = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "pointSize");
   gl.vertexAttribPointer(aPointSize, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 0, 0);
   gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aPointSize);
   ```
4. As soon as I bind the buffer and set the bufferSubData in the mousemove event, then no points are shown when I move the mouse.  Note:  index is just a variable that increases with the mouse move to identify the position in the vertex related to the pixel.  Here is the code in the mousemove event:

   ```
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, aPointSizeBuffer);
   pointSizes[index] = fpointSize;  //this is the selected size
   gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, index, pointSizes[index]);
   ```

   It does not matter if I do any of these things:

   ```
         gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, index, fpointSize);
   ```

   or even:

   ```
         gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, index,1);
   ```

Thanks again for any help

Answer (score 2):

`gl.bufferSubData` expects the 3rd argument to be a TypeArray. Your `pointSizes[index]` appears to be an uint8. Try use `pointSizes.subarray(index, index+1)` and see if that fixes it.